# how can my program tell if code is in a interrupt handler?(riscv32)

Tags: linux, esp32, riscv, freertos, riscv32

Is there an exact way to tell if code is running in a interrupt handler? Since I need to distinguish between interrupt context and non-interrupt context to use correct FreeRTOS API(eg：xSemaphoreGive/xSemaphoreGiveFromISR)

Referring to the arm platform, whether in interrupt handler can be obtained through IPSR or SCB->ICSR.Similarly, on riscv, we can see that the mcause register contains the execption code field. Can I use this field to directly determine whether the current code is in an interrupt handler function?

I want the confirm solutions of my questions,Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! While you're waiting for an answer, please take the [tour] to learn how this site works, and you might want to read "[ask]" and other pages of the [help]. Then please come back and [edit] your question to show what you found already during your research, for example chapters of the documentation (link to it), and why exactly this does not help you.

Comment: Your question body appears to be about whether a solution you have determined will work.  It is better to leave it open since an answer "yes, that will work" may be correct, but it may not be the best solution, or if it is, your unexhibited implementation of it may not be correct, even if your _description_ of it sounds plausible.  Generally ask for a solution rather than asking _about_ a specific solution.

Comment: Do you mean "how can I tell for the purpose of debugging" or "how can my program tell in run-time"?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.